# Author and title of poem: "Follow, follow me into the South, ..."

Tags: identification-request, poetry

> Follow, follow me into the South,
>           And if you are brave and wise
>   I'll buy you laughter for your mouth,
>           Sorrow for your eyes.
>
> I'll buy you laughter, wild and sweet,
>           And sorrow, grey and still,
>   But you must follow with willing feet
>           Over the farthest hill.
>
> Follow, follow me into the South
>           You may return tomorrow
>   Wearing my kisses on your mouth,
>           In your eyes my sorrow.

Can anyone tell me the author and title of this poem?

Comment: Where did you find this poem? Or do you have all the words memorised?

Comment: @Scott: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

This is ‘**Ballad**’ by **Marjorie Allen Seiffert** (1885–1970), first published in the collection [*A Woman of Thirty*](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/4556) (1919).